# Usage of 'will' and 'would' in a question

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, will-shall

What is the difference between

> When will XYZ bank release the results of clerks?

and

> When would XYZ Bank release the results of clerks?

Which one is the formal way to ask the HR of the bank.

Please explain the difference between 'will' and 'would' (in a question) with examples.

Comment: use present tense 'is/are'! We use it for the events that are sure to happen. 'The train *leaves* on Monday'. Likewise - *When are the results of [Exam's name]?*

Comment: Both refers to the future.  The use of  will  in the question is a direct way of asking a question,  whereas the use of would is an indirect or polite way of asking a question.

Comment: *Will* is fine.  The simple present is also fine, if used properly.  *Would* seems a little off here.  The more important issue is how to rephrase "the results of clerks".